# internet explorer 11 style calculation on :active

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, pseudo-class

Hi stack overflow community :)

this is driving me crazy ...
it is about internet explorer 11 (didnt test previous versions, doesnt matter).

Sorry for the german screenshots of IE etc.

**The Problem:**

I have this huge table, about 1500 lines with a noticeable amount of elements inside.
So one cause of the problem is the amount of elements, probably exceeding
1500 lines * 7 cells * 2 HTML elements.
This is a fact i am not allowed to change ;)
Clicking on the scrollbar button triggers a style calculation of all elements inside
the scrollable element. Due to the amount of the elements this style calculation
takes about 300ms, therefore noticeable.

The code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .fooooooo:active {
        /* just remove this EMPTY rule to "fix" IE? */
    }

    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    html, body {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .screen-container {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
</style>

<section class="screen-container">
    <table><!-- huge --></table>
</section>
```

**How to reproduce:**

Open IE "devtools", start a profiling session and just click on the scrollbar button of the `<section>` element.
Stop the profiling session and glance at the green bars - about 300ms style calculations. One for the click (":focus",":active"?)
on the button, one for the :blur on the button?
@see screenshot and or try the fiddle. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3tjmgdq/2/)

[screenshot of jsfiddle with IE devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pc8q.png)

**More information i found out so far:**

1# The very existence of the CSS rule ".fooooooo:active" is enough. Notice that this rule has
no rules nor does it match any element.
Just removing it "prevents" the 300ms style calculation.

2# Moving the scrollbar away from the `<section>` to the `<body>` element also "fixes"
the style calculation problem. Probably because "body:active" "is not allowed"?. At least i cant
get it to work ;)

3# it doesnt matter if we have a huge `<table>` or a huge soup of `<div>`'s

I appreciate any information you can give me :)

**Solutions i can NOT take:**

- Moving the scrollbar to the `<body>`
- Replacing :active with JS and regular .active CSS classes.
- Reducing the amount of elements (paging etc.) (my dear and lovely customer want it like that!)

Comment: We're having a similar problem when using big HTML pages with bootstrap - it clearly seems to be a bug in IE. We're trying to work around it by just removing use of :active :-(